# Как передать значение промиса из одного файла в другой?

Tags: node.js, axios

Имею плохую ситуацию. Использую express и axios, хочу передать значение промиса но никак не могут. Есть файл сервера, аутентификации и корзинки. Я получая переменную токена доступа в файле сервера и должен передать её функции корзинки. Когда всё пишется в одном файле проблем не возникает, когда я пишу с отдельным файлом аутентификации тоже проблем не возникает, но когда я пишу ещё отдельный файл корзинки, тогда ничего не выходит.

Тело файл сервера

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');           // For web server
const Axios = require('axios');               // A Promised base http client
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');    // Receive JSON format
const querystring = require('querystring');

let app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

const config = require('./config');

const PORT = config.credentials.PORT; // import from bim start.js
var FORGE_CLIENT_ID = 'ZqbXzFL8NMXtovqJrLG0O9f5Ar3nQRoE';
var FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET = 'PM4vPHZGQArq99qn';
const scopes = 'data:read data:write data:create bucket:create bucket:read';

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err);
  res.status(err.statusCode).json(err);
})
```

Файл аутентификации

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const Axios = require('axios');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const querystring = require('querystring');        

const config = require('../config');

var FORGE_CLIENT_ID = 'ZqbXzFL8NMXtovqJrLG0O9f5Ar3nQRoE';
var FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET = 'PM4vPHZGQArq99qn';
const scopes = 'data:read data:write data:create bucket:create bucket:read';

let router = express.Router();
router.use(bodyParser.json());

module.exports = oauth => {
  return Axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate',
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      },
      data: querystring.stringify({
        client_id: FORGE_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret: FORGE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        scope: scopes
      })
    })
  }
```

Продолжение аутентификации в файле сервера

```
let access_token = '';
var oauth = require('./routes/oauth')
app.get('/api/forge/oauth', function(req, res) {
  oauth()
  .then(function (response) {
      // Success
      // let's save token into the varible access_token
      access_token = response.data.access_token;
      console.log(response);
      console.log(access_token);
      // Then, the app is routed to, which creates a shared bucket for our app.
      res.redirect('/api/forge/datamanagement/bucket/create');
  })
    .catch(function (error) {
      // Failed
      console.error(error);
      res.send('Failed to authenticate');
    });
  });
```

Файл корзинки

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const Axios = require('axios');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const querystring = require('querystring');        

const config = require('../config');

const bucketKey = config.credentials.client_id.toLowerCase() + '_my_first_full_viewer_bucket';
const policyKey = 'transient'; // Expires in 24hr


module.exports = bucketCreate => {
  return Axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
      'bucketKey': bucketKey,
      'policyKey': policyKey
    })
  })
}
```

Продолжение части корзинки в файле сервера

```
var bucketCreate = require('./routes/bucketCreate')
app.get('/api/forge/datamanagement/bucket/create', function (req, res) {
bucketCreate()
    .then(function (response) {
      // Success
      console.log(response);
      res.redirect('/api/forge/datamanagement/bucket/detail');
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      if (error.response && error.response.status == 409) {
        console.log('Bucket already exists, skip creation.');
        res.redirect('/api/forge/datamanagement/bucket/detail');
      }
      // Failed
      console.log(error);
      res.send('Failed to create a new bucket');
    });
});
```

Мне не удаётся передать значение access_token из файла сервера в файл корзинки, где буду происходить дальнейшие операция с ними. Мне так же не удавалась передать эту переменную в файл аутентификации, поэтому я пошёл обходным путём и получил часть файла аутентификации в фале сервера, а манипуляции с access_token выполнил в файле сервера.
Код ошибки 401(если не ошибаюсь, или 403). В любом случаи буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

отредактируйте файл корзины

```
module.exports = bucketCreate => {
  return Axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets',
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer ' + access_token
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
      'bucketKey': bucketKey,
      'policyKey': policyKey
    }).then(response => { 
        return {
           response, // передаем нашу response дальше
           access_token,  // передаем токен
           and_more:'const_test' //также вы можете добавлять еще что либо 
        }
    })
  })
}
```

а в файле который используете сделайте деструкцию

```
bucketCreate()
    .then(function ({response,access_token,and_more}) {
         console.log(response,access_token,and_more)
        // ... ваш код
    })
```

или

```
bucketCreate()
    .then(function (res) {
         console.log(res.response,res.access_token,res.and_more)
        // ... ваш код
    })
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, вот другой способ решения https://toster.ru/q/600308, а вот и продолжение https://toster.ru/q/600652.